# Button position in responsive design

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change positions of buttons in mobile mode,relative to text.I tried different position/absolute ,but it didn't take effect.Buttons don't stay relative to the text they stay on the same  position on the mobile mode.
Someone can help?

```css
.button {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 200px;
  left: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 12.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
  color: #162636;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .button {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-12-sm">
    <div class="info-wrapper">
      <div class="col-2 col-12-sm">
        <div class="center">
          <div class="wine-bottle">
            <img src="assets/images/gaetan-chardonnay.png" alt="Chardonnay" width="125" height="auto">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-10 col-12-sm">
        <div class="wine-description">
          <h3>GAETAN-Chardonnay</h3>
          <p>White, dry wine made from Chardonnay grapes, with a pleasant, sparkling golden-yellow color. Tasteful fruit flavors, with notes of wildflowers and fresh white berries, flowing smoothly into a feeling of slightly sweet tropical fruit and honey.
            The taste is crisp and at the same time soft, with fine acidity and a good length of the finish. The after-taste preserves the sweet aromatic notes, reminiscing of white peach and flowers, with a sense of freshness and refinement.</p>
          <a href="chardonnay-bg.html" class="button">View more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: which version of BS you are using?

Comment: and on Desktop do you have the desired result? explain a bit more that how you want it on Desktop and mobile?

Comment: yes.I can positioned it on Desktop mode.I want on Desktop mode to be on bottom right and on mobile to be bottom center.Problem is that buttons stay on same position on mobile mode.It's not Bootstrap it's simple grid.

Answer (score 0):

You're not positioning your button in your media query other than using `relative`and `block`. It also can work with using just `@media` instead of `@media screen only and`. For example.

```
@media(max-width: 768px){.button{position: absolute; 
left: 500px;}}
```

Comment: I try it but with no result.

Comment: Alternatively you could use`.button a`. Important shouldn't be used unless absolutely necessary but if absolutely necessarily then `!important`.

Comment: Failing that use the url as your selector, failing that try specificity with the div class `. wine-description>. button {foo}}` or`.wine-description.button{foo}}`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you need this, this is not a good approch to use button with position absolute with custom hard coded pixel position, but if really this is you need, and on mobile want it center, then try this,

to make it center on mobile, add this to your media query on button

```
**left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);**

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
.button{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);
      }
}
```